# Bundle custom fonts into macOS standalone application using Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, fonts

I am new to macOS standalone application development and I am working on fixing the issues in it. I am running with an issue where the custom fonts not getting applied to controls present in the application. I am using Xcode 11.3 in macOS Mojave 10.14

There is already a fonts folder added to the project which contains all the font files (.ttf) extension. I have referred the "fonts" folder using the key "Application fonts resource path" in the Info.plist file. Even after applying all these changes the controls are getting referred to system font instead of the embedded font.

Also, the custom fonts which are added to the project is not being shown in the Font dropdown list of Attribute inspector.

Can you please suggest on what needs to be done in order to embed the custom fonts into the project and also show these custom fonts in fonts dropdown list?

Answer (score 1):

## Install the font

On your macOS, double click on all the fonts you'd like to use. Following window will appear for each:

[image]

Click on the *Install Font* button.

## Attributes inspector

You can now choose your font. Remember, only installed fonts are listed. Fonts bundled with your application are not. Select your custom font.

[image]

## Bundle fonts

### Add a new Copy Files phase

- Set subpaths to `Fonts`
- Drop all the font files there

[image]

### Info.plist

- Add a new row *Application fonts resource path* (`ATSApplicationFontsPath`)
- Set value to `Fonts` (must match copy files phase subpath)

[image]

## Test

How to test that fonts are bundled correctly:

- Close the storyboard (Xcode)
- Launch Font Book
- Right click on your custom font and disable it
- Launch your application and test that all the custom fonts are bundled properly and work as expected
- Launch Font Book
- Right click on your custom font and enable it again

[image]

**WARNING**

> **Do NOT open the storyboard file if you disable/remove your custom font.**

You'll get the following warning if you do ...

[image]

... and all your custom font settings are gone. You **can** open the storyboard file again, but you have to enable/install your custom font.

Comment: Yeah i have already done this.. Installing the fonts on my macOS has fixed the issue. If i build a setup and provide to the client then how the fonts get automatically installed on client machine. Can you please suggest on how this can be done?

Comment: You don't need to install them on your client computers. It will work if they're bundled with your app. The only reason to install them on your machine is to be able to use these fonts in the Attributes inspector.

Comment: The process which you have mentioned in the comment is the process of bundling the fonts with our app. right?

Comment: 1) Always bundle fonts with your app (Info.plist & Copy Files build phase). Then you can run this app on your computer or on any other computers without an issue. 2) Install fonts on a computer where you are editing storyboard file(s) to be able to select the custom font from the font dropdown list.

Comment: Yeah sure... Thanks for the update. Will this be applicable if a setup is being provided in the form of .dmg format?

Comment: DMG is just a mountable disk image which can contain your application bundle. And your application bundle contains these fonts. It's irrelevant how you distribute your application bundle. The answer is yes.

Comment: i am building a .dmg mountable disk image file and sending it for testing but when they open it they are experiencing the font loading issues.I am building the .dmg file using Disk utility.. Am i going wrong anywhere in building the .dmg file?  Do you have any steps for creating the .dmg file for our application.

Comment: If you have a problem with DMG, you should ask another question, do not use comments for it. `ATSApplicationFontsPath` should work as it is available since macOS 10.0+. As an alternative to DMG, just archive/compress (zip) the application bundle folder and send the zip file instead of DMG.